# Draw a line with curves

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, line

I took time looking for ways to make a simple graph, only about showing a line that goes from one point to another point and curves along the way that will be the benchmarks, I've only found a way to make complex graphs with straight lines, would appreciate any reference or support, thanks
I leave a picture of what I want

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DCRr.png

Comment: What have you found then? How have you considered creating the line yourself?

Comment: I found chart lines but curves, such as https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart

Comment: Look here at "Getting Comfortable with Curves" section:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/34003/core-graphics-tutorial-curves-and-layers
Work for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz2D(Core Graphic Framework) is suggested.

You can draw straight line, rectangle, circle, ellipse, curve(of a circle), or Bezier curve.